# How to bypass lazy loading of reactive expressions in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, lazy-evaluation

In a shiny app, let's say I have data that is so large such that I only want to perform operations once.

The `server.R` script could look like:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  data <- matrix(some_x, nrow=1000, ncol=5000)

  calculation <- observe({
    data <<- some_transformation(data, input$coefficient)
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(some_other_transformation(data))
  })

  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    plot(some_other_transformation(data))
  })

  output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
    invisible(input$coefficient)
    plot(some_other_transformation(data))
  })
})
```

Why is the reactive expression for `plot3` the only one that evaluates? Does the presence of the `input` variable "induce" evaluation of this expression?

My main question is: How can I "induce" expression of plots 1 and 2 without somehow mentioning the `input` variable?

Comment: I think you would normally call the data different, i.e. like this: `calculation <- observe({some_transformation(data, input$coefficient)}); output$plot1 <- renderPlot({plot(calculation())})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're performing a calculation then an observer is the wrong tool for the job, see [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html). If you only want a calculation performed once then you should have an action button. If you want the action to be performed every time the input is changed, then you should use a reactive:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  data <- matrix(some_x, nrow=1000, ncol=5000)

  trans_data <- reactive({
    some_transformation(data, input$coefficient)
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(some_other_transformation(trans_data()))
  })

  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    plot(some_other_transformation(trans_data()))
  })

  output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
    invisible(input$coefficient)
    plot(some_other_transformation(trans_data()))
  })
})
```

The reactive is only run once, see [this](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson6/):

> Reactive expressions are a bit smarter than regular R functions. They cache their values and know when their values have become outdated. What does this mean? The first time that you run a reactive expression, the expression will save its result in your computer’s memory. The next time you call the reactive expression, it can return this saved result without doing any computation (which will make your app faster).

Comment: In this solution using reactive(), aren't we just calling the same transformation 3 times?

Comment: @Megatron, actually no! That's one of the beautiful things about Shiny, please see my edits

Comment: Good call! Thanks bud